# Using Angularjs filter to differentiate between 1 and 10

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a simple filter, and I want to filter wordsDictory.word according to the ng-model lesson. The filters works in most cases, but when I search for "1" I get entries from both "1" and "10"; is there a way to make the filter search for just "1".

```
input<type='text' ng-model='lesson'>

<div> wordsDictionary.word | filter:lesson</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this. You can write a custom filter:

```
filter('customSearch', function () {
    return function (input, searchStr) {
        if (input == searchStr) {
            return input;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    };
});
```

There is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrpWw/) using it. Try to enter "1" and after that "10" into the input field.